# number of possibilities for a 6 digit number with contraints

Tags: combinatorics, combinations

We have a 6 digit number _ _ _ _ _ _

```
the constraints are : 
1. the 6th digit is the sum of 2th and the 4th digit.
2. the 5th digit is the sum of 1th and the 3th digit.
3. digits can be from 1 to 9. Repetition of digits is allowed.
```

how many possibilities are there?

I have tried something, written down every possibly combination of sum of two digits that doesn't exceed 9. I got 36. then multiplied it by 4. but it's not correct

Comment: Surely you have tried something, no?  When you edit your post to include your efforts, I also suggest that you indicate which digit you mean by (say) the $6^{th}$...if you mean the leading digit then, presumably, you want to exclude the case where it is $0$.

Comment: I've edited the post. the digits can be from 1 to 9. I have tried something, written down every possibly combination of sum of two digits that doesn't exceed 9. I got 36. then multiplied it by 4. but it's not correct

Comment: Let's count the unordered pairs of non-zero digits that add to a digit:  if the max is $9$ then there are none.  If the max is $8$ then there is one.  If $7$ then two.  If $6$ then three.  If $5$ then four.  if $4$ then four.  if $3$ then three.  if $2$ then two.  if $1$ then one.  Thus $1+2+3+4+4+3+2+1=20$.  Of these there are four doubles and $16$ non-doubles.  Can you finish from here?  Why would you multiply by $4$?

Comment: thank you. Unfortunately I didn't quite get it..
The options for digits are :
`1,1 ; 1,2; 1,3; 1,4; 1,5; 1,6; 1,7; 1,8;
2,1 ; 2,2; 2,3 ; 2,4; 2,5 ; 2,6 ; 2,7;
3,1 ; 3,2; 3,3; 3,4 ; 3,5; 3,6;
4,1; 4,2; 4,3 ; 4,4; 4,5; 
5,1; 5,2; 5,3; 5;4
6,1; 6,2 ; 6,3
7,1 ; 7,2
8;1
`

Comment: which is 36 options. not we have constraint 1 and constraint 2, in both there are 36*2 options. That's why I multiplied by 4

Comment: I am also getting $36$ ordered pairs, four doubles and sixteen non-doubles among the unordered pairs gives $4+2\times 16=4+32=36$.  But I can't understand why you would multiply by $4$?  you need to pick two ordered pairs.  That's $36^2$.

Comment: ohhh I see now. I got it messed up unfortunately .. 
Thank you very much

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's call the digits $d_1, d_2, \ldots d_6$. Clearly the first four digits determine the whole number, but there are constraints on those digits in order to ensure that $d_5$ and $d_6$ stay in range.

So, for example, choosing $d_1=1$ gives $8$ options for $d_3$ to keep $d_5$ in range. Choosing $d_1=2$ gives $7$ options for $d_3$, etc., leading to a total of $8+7+6+\cdots+1=36$ options for the $d_1,d_3$ set. This agrees with part of your reasoning.

Independently of that choice, by the same calculations we similarly have $36$ options for $d_2,d_4$. Clearly any one choice for $d_1,d_3$ can be associated with any choice for $d_2,d_4,$ so overall the total choices for the whole six digit number are $36\cdot 36 = 1296$.